# DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync not finding same number of COM ports

Tags: xamarin, uwp, rfcomm

I have a Xamarin UWP app which needs to listen to a device on a COM port.  The ultimate purpose of this is for the customer to use Microsoft surfaces and GPS devices and let their associates wander around and take GPS readings.

I am attempting to enumerate the available ports such that the user can select which one their gps device is broadcasting on. The code I am using is as follows:

```
    string serialDeviceType = RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort);
    DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(serialDeviceType);
```

On the first surface I was working with the 'devices' collection got 4 members, "Com1", "Com2", "Com3" and "Serial Port", and I was ultimately able to get everything working correctly. I have another device, however, and on this one I only get "Serial Port" in the 'devices' collection with the same code.

The devices that I was listening to were different in both cases.  In the first I was listening to a Trimble R1, in the second to an XGPS160, but I wouldn't expect that to affect how many DeviceInformations would come back from this call, that seems more like a difference between the two Surfaces.

Does anyone know why one Surface would return Com1-Com3 from the FindAllAsync call, while the other did not? That is, if I wanted to deliberately create this result, how would I go about doing it?

-Thanks,
Walter

Comment: Hi,Have you got why be the different names^.^

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Serial function driver creates a symbolic link name for a serial port and registers a GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT device interface for the port. By definition, a serial port is a COM port only if it has a COM port device interface associated with it.

For a Plug and Play serial device, external naming is controlled by a **SerialSkipExternalNaming** entry value under the hardware key of the device. If the **SerialSkipExternalNaming** entry value does not exist, or its value is zero, Serial creates a COM port device interface; otherwise, Serial does not create a COM port interface. Serial does not support this entry value for a legacy COM port and always creates a COM port device interface for a legacy COM port.

Then,diferent computer may has different names for Serial Port.Here is [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/serports/external-naming-of-com-ports).